# If a two-variable function under some constraint has only one critical point, can I classify the point as an extrema (global)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the critical points of the function $z=x^2+y^2$ under the constraint $\frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{3}=1$.

Hey everyone.

I used the Lagrange multiplier to find the critical point $(\frac{36}{25}, \frac{48}{25})$. Now, I am not sure whether to use the second derivative test to classify the point, since I don't know if the test holds under this constraint.

I would appreciate your help, thank you :)

Comment: As lab's answer suggests, $z$ is essentially a one-variable function in either $x$ or $y$. For your question, though, if the "second derivative" here is known to satisfy [certain conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian), then you can tell that the candidate point is a local maximum or minimum.

Comment: @Vim Thank you very much Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint defines a line $\ell$ in the $(x,y)$-plane. Geometric qualitative considerations tell us that the function $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2$ will take a global minimum on $\ell$, and this global minimum is then a local minimum as well, hence will be brought to the fore by Lagrange's method. Lagrange's method found one point; hence this is the point you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

$3x=12-4y$

$$9z=(3x)^2+9y^2=(12-4y)^2+9y^2=144+25y^2-96y=144+25\left(y-\dfrac{48}{25}\right)^2-\dfrac{48^2}{25}$$

$$\ge144-\dfrac{48^2}{25}$$